# Windows 7 recreate my .exe/.dll files

Tags: windows-7

i have a few programs that check if file exist, and if its old version delete him and paste the new one. However under Windows 7 Professional i can't delete the file some System process is always restoring it (same with the dll files) and as you can imagine a lot of programs are crashing because of that behaviour. So WHAT SERVICE/PROCESS can lock/recreate/restore files? I have disabled System Recovery.

Comment: What kind of files are those? Could you mention/show some examples?

Comment: Well pretty much every .exe/.dll file that programs use. For example - Steam, i can't update it, because the System process is always restoring the old version. btw the System process have no path and no way to identify what process is causing this

Comment: Did you install your PC? Did you *ever* let it somewhere in idle without password? I'm thinking about some kind of rollback software, but those usually roll only every reboot.

Comment: No its reinstalled Windows 7, not a lot programs and does not have any rollback or backup software installed (disabled Volume Shadow Copy). The problem is that windows restores EVERY dll/exe file no matter system or not, no matter where is installed. If the file is accessed by some program some kind of software is starting to protecting the file and i can't get rid of it. After few minutes everything is back to normal, if the file is not accessed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem - It was disabled Microsoft services - Program Compatibility and Application Expirience

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things here:

1. [Windows File Protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193). See this [post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/) for a way to circumvent it.
2. MSI (Microsoft Windows Installer) restoring files to the original state.

The only way to avoid this is use a valid update package of those programs to update the dlls.

Comment: No its not matter of SFC, cause this are not system files, i dunno about MSI, but it cant be the problem since Python generated executables are still affected by this.